# Flow in visualforce page not displaying in lightning(Looks like Classic)

Tags: visualforce, lightning, salesforce-classic

I have included the flows in visualforce page,but it is showing in classic view,How to achieve this in Lightning page.

**Below is code**

```
<apex:page controller="IDFSubmissionFlowController">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <head>
        <apex:includeLightning />
     </head>

     <body  class="slds-scope">
       <flow:interview name="Invention_Disclosure_Submission" interview="{!IDFSubmissionFlow}"/>
       <apex:iframe src="apex/IDFMultipleFilesUpload?Id={!FlowIDFId}" height="1200px" width="1000px" rendered="{!IF((FlowIDFId +'') !='',true,false)}"/>
     </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: See this similar post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/133939

Answer (score 1):

You can Try `Lightning Components`

Here is the Code for Calling Flow in Lightning Component:

**Component:**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    init : function (component) {
        // To Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
        var flow = component.find("flowData");
        // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow's Unique Name(API Name).
        flow.startFlow("New_Customer_Flow");
    },
})
```